# Robotic Arm- Moveit2- Controllers spawner error

Tags: ros2, moveit, ros2-control, gazebo-ros2-control, ros2-controllers

Moveit2 planning successfully but gives error at execution, also the controllers are not spawning.

```
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-1]: process started with pid [12053]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [12055]
[INFO] [move_group-3]: process started with pid [12057]
[INFO] [rviz2-4]: process started with pid [12059]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-5]: process started with pid [12061]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [12063]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [12065]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [12067]
[static_transform_publisher-1] [INFO] [1697187566.879881834] [static_transform_publisher0]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-1] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-1] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-1] from 'world' to 'base_link'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1697187566.895658989] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
[ros2_control_node-5]   what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  fake_components/GenericSystem mock_components/GenericSystem test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem test_system
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.930362280] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_last_arm_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.931227884] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.931679923] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_lower_arm_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.931980794] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_upper_arm_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.932258175] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.932532359] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment first_finger_bottom_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.932789306] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment first_finger_top_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.933055903] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment first_yaw_arm_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.933323869] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment fourth_finger_bottom_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.933674532] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment fourth_finger_top_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.934012821] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment last_arm_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.934344593] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment lower_arm_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.934662011] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment second_finger_bottom_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.934963719] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment second_finger_top_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.935256924] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment third_finger_bottom_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.935576422] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment third_finger_top_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.935883378] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment upper_arm_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1697187566.936181296] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment yaw_arm_link
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.958922458] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.0353979 seconds
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.959560665] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'robot'...
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.983259039] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.983625340] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.984423737] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.986487592] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.986611783] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.988947050] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.989020900] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.989955573] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.990479612] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1697187566.991450585] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1697187566.991485212] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187566.992630854] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.019227263] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-5]: process has died [pid 12061, exit code -6, cmd '/home/u/ws_moveit2/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params__8xf8uc2 --params-file /home/u/ws_moveit2/install/my_bot_moveit_config/share/my_bot_moveit_config/config/ros2_controllers.yaml'].
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025499157] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025520013] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025523226] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025544890] [moveit_ros.fix_workspace_bounds]: Param 'ompl.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025555769] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025559178] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025566655] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025570071] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.050000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025579960] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025587762] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025592179] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025594353] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025596621] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025598511] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.025600453] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.027174798] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.031441210] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.038614695] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Available plugins: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP 
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.038644134] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.040860297] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [CIRC]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.040920705] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.043298792] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [LIN]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.043344586] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.044814821] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [PTP]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.044917136] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'Pilz Industrial Motion Planner'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.048046457] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'chomp'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.056065710] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'CHOMP'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059151932] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059176360] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059181134] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059206882] [moveit_ros.fix_workspace_bounds]: Param 'chomp.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059224588] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059230250] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059243633] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059249648] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.050000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059255178] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059269605] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059274956] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059278461] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059286854] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059289842] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.059293187] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.091197421] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for arm_controller
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.093529467] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for gripper_controller
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.093715984] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.093775801] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.094093431] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.094112176] [move_group.move_group]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1697187567.102956102] [spawner_gripper_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187567.121632948] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187567.121715416] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.121889972] [move_group.move_group]: 
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3] * MoveGroup using: 
[move_group-3] *     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
[move_group-3] *     - ClearOctomapService
[move_group-3] *     - CartesianPathService
[move_group-3] *     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
[move_group-3] *     - GetPlanningSceneService
[move_group-3] *     - KinematicsService
[move_group-3] *     - MoveAction
[move_group-3] *     - MotionPlanService
[move_group-3] *     - QueryPlannersService
[move_group-3] *     - StateValidationService
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.121940681] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1697187567.121949341] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] You can start planning now!
[move_group-3] 
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1697187567.127595704] [spawner_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1697187567.128612861] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187567.137121161] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-4]          at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1697187569.117468002] [spawner_gripper_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1697187569.141786421] [spawner_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1697187569.142276443] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1697187570.235144115] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.252008437] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.745954199] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.446447 seconds
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.745993705] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'robot'...
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.772555378] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.773657012] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.782757529] [interactive_marker_display_94150152796080]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.790602207] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group arm
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.790627018] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm' in namespace ''
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.798251673] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.798971351] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group arm
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.804546527] [interactive_marker_display_94150152796080]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1697187570.836998777] [interactive_marker_display_94150152796080]: Service response received for initialization
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1697187571.129730769] [spawner_gripper_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1697187571.154380514] [spawner_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1697187571.154383279] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1697187573.145275905] [spawner_gripper_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1697187573.167301716] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1697187573.167570778] [spawner_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1697187575.158776311] [spawner_gripper_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1697187575.181961250] [spawner_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1697187575.182516396] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [ERROR] [1697187577.171560451] [spawner_gripper_controller]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-8] [ERROR] [1697187577.195464327] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1697187577.195558387] [spawner_arm_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 12065, exit code 1, cmd '/home/u/ws_moveit2/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner gripper_controller --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-8]: process has died [pid 12067, exit code 1, cmd '/home/u/ws_moveit2/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 12063, exit code 1, cmd '/home/u/ws_moveit2/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner arm_controller --ros-args'].
```

At the end of the terminal output, you can see the spawning failed.

How can I fix the spawner error?

I am launching `moveit2 demo.launch`.

I am using the [default tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html).

Comment: See the the error at the top of you log > [ros2_control_node-5] what(): According to the loaded plugin
> descriptions the class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base
> class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist.
> Declared types are fake_components/GenericSystem
> mock_components/GenericSystem
> test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes
> test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem test_system have you installed gazebo_ros2_control and sourced it?

Comment: Please edit your post to include a link to the tutorial you followed to install ros2 humble and gazebo. Also show us the exact command line(s) you are using to start the simulation.